# Bind M-[ and M-] when not in a terminal

Tags: key-bindings, terminal-emacs

What is the correct way to bind keys only for X frames? E.g. some key combinations are part of terminal escape sequences, but otherwise should be bindable when not running in a terminal.

Currently, I use an `after-make-frame-functions` hook:

```
(defun my-setup-nontty-bindings (frame)
  "Set up TTY-incompatible keybinds for FRAME, if it's not a TTY."
    (unless overriding-terminal-local-map
      (setq overriding-terminal-local-map (make-sparse-keymap)))
    (define-key overriding-terminal-local-map (kbd "M-[") 'cs/forward-or-backward-sexp)
    (define-key overriding-terminal-local-map (kbd "M-]") 'er/expand-region)))
(add-hook 'after-make-frame-functions 'my-setup-nontty-bindings)
```

This almost works, however:

- A frame is not exactly the same as a terminal, and `overriding-terminal-local-map` is a per-terminal, not per-frame variable;
- A non-nil `overriding-terminal-local-map` breaks international input, which is apparently [by design](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Invoking-the-Input-Method.html).

Comment: Is it not possible to predicate the bindings on `(display-graphic-p)`, e.g. `(when (display-graphic-p) (define-key ...) ...)`?

Comment: I don't think you want to mess with `overriding-terminal-local-map`.  It doesn't really have anything to do with terminal vs. graphical frames.  You should probably just use `global-set-key` and `display-graphic-p` like @Basil suggested.

Comment: No, that won't work because they are part of an escape sequence. Defining them in the global key map breaks all keys in the terminal whose sequence includes the `ESC-[` sequence (i.e. arrow keys, F-keys...)